# Is there a difference in performance in only updating values that has been changed or updating both unchanged and changed?

Tags: sql-server

I have a settings page where users can choose to update their information. As their information are shown to them as default values in text fields where they can choose to edit, when they submit the form I will update their information even if they aren't changed.

So is it better to check if values have changed before performing the update or is it fine to just continue updating both unchanged and changed values?

Answer (score 3):

In [my tests](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/conditional-updates), as long as we are talking about in-row columns and no additional indexes, it always made sense to just update the entire row, rather than cherry-pick the individual columns that have changed values.

This may be different when we are dealing with LOB columns, which are usually stored off-row, and have some additional overhead (both with the check for equality and the update itself).

I didn't test ensuring that *at least one* column had changed before bothering to perform the update at all. That *might* be worth checking and avoiding the work when it isn't necessary, depending on your table/index structure, and what % of the time you try to perform an update when nothing has changed.

I also didn't test the impact when the columns you are updating are also in non-clustered indexes. The more indexes, potentially, the more likely you will gain from checking first. If you have 18 non-clustered indexes that contain a certain column, and that column value hasn't actually changed, it might make sense to avoid that update.

You can follow the same testing techniques to gauge any of these...

Comment: Hmm, what about indexed columns? Doesn't it make sense to exclude un-changed indexed columns? Otherwise you add the overhead of unnecessarily updating the index

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Possibly. Worth some tests.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name In the article I did treat one case (three non-clustered indexes), and even there, it was still almost always favorable to just blindly update all columns. Perhaps the threshold is different depending on the number / complexity / type of indexes.